# Transformation of Random Variables $Y=|X|$ CDF METHOD

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable with probability density function $f_x(x)$ and cumulative distributive function $F_x(a)$:

$$f_x(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2\theta}e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}},  & \text{if $x\geq0$} \\
\frac{1}{2\theta}e^{\frac{x}{\theta}}, & \text{if $x<0$}
\end{cases}$$

$$F_x(a) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{a}{\theta}},  & \text{if $a\geq0$} \\
\frac{1}{2}e^{\frac{a}{\theta}}, & \text{if $a<0$}
\end{cases}$$

Derive the probability density function of $Y = |X|$.

My attempt:
I notice that this is not a one-to-one transformation, so I will use the CDF Method to find $f_y(y)$. To do this, I need the support of $Y$:
$$S_y=(|X| : x\in R)=(0,\infty)$$
I am not entirely sure how to find the support since $f(x)$ is a piece-wise function, the above is my attempt. Continuing on, we have our support so now we have to derive $F_y(a)$

$$F_y(a) = P[Y\leq a] = P[|X|\leq a]$$
Where $a\in(0,\infty)$.

This is where I am stuck. Not only am I unsure that I derived the right support of $Y$, I am unsure on the next steps after $P[|X|\leq a]$. The fact that there is an $|X|$ is really tripping me up. Normally you can work with just the X and start working with $F_x(a)$ but at this step I do not know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument for the support is fine. (Whether or not it contains zero I think is a matter of convention.) To proceed with your approach for the CDF, note 
$$\Pr(\lvert X \rvert \leq a) = \Pr(-a \leq X \leq a) = \int_{-a}^0 f_x(x)dx + \int_0^a f_x(x)dx.$$
By the way, $X$ is symmetric; this helps simplify the integral but should also give you more intuition for the answer (beyond a simple computation of the above). Also, this approach holds in general, even for one-to-one transformations, e.g. if $Y = X^2$ then $\Pr(Y \leq a) = \Pr(-\sqrt{a} \leq X \leq \sqrt{a})$, and more generally if $Y = f(X)$ then you just have to think about when $f(x) \leq a$.